# Getting ERROR 502 when trying to run a Docker Flask app on App Engine

Tags: python, docker, google-app-engine, flask

I'd like to deploy a Docker image on App Engine which contains a basic Flask app. Also, this app will be a web-socket endpoint for my front-end.

Deployment is a success. **But i'm getting an error 502.**

I've read the doc, I've tried many configuration but I don't get it works, if someone has any idea, i'd highly appreciate.

[image: error]

[image]

**My project structure :**

```
- socket/
  - socket/
    - main.py
    - Dockerfile
    - app.yaml
    - requirements.txt
  - cloudbuild.yaml
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This will be only used locally. App Engine will use gunicorn.
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask==1.0.3
Flask-Sockets==0.2.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:2.7

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 8080

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn","--bind=0.0.0.0:8080", "-k flask_sockets.worker", "main:app"]
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
service: socket
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT -k flask_sockets.worker main:app
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
network:
  session_affinity: true
```

**cloudbuild.yaml**

```
steps:
  # Decrypt env secrets
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    args:
      - kms
      - decrypt
      - --ciphertext-file=./socket/conf/gcp_credentials.json.enc
      - --plaintext-file=./socket/conf/gcp_credentials.json
      - --location=global
      - --keyring=cloudbuild-env
      - --key=cloudbuild-env
    id: decrypt
  # Build the docker image
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/tweets-socket-dataflow', './socket/' ]
    id: build
  # Deploy the image
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
    args: ['app', 'deploy', './socket/app.yaml', '-v', '1-socket-latest']
    id: deploy
timeout: 600s
```

---

This actually works **locally**.

**Docker command used**

```
docker run -it -d -p 8080:8080 144005a4e426
```

**docker ps**

```
c2763d0b8b75        144005a4e426        "gunicorn --bind=0.0…"   3 seconds ago       Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   sleepy_ganguly
```

**http:127.0.0.1:8080**

[image]

Comment: `docker ps` please

Comment: Hmm no I don't get my "hello world" thing. just a blank page with a big 502 bad gateway

Comment: @frankegoesdown you want the docker ps when running locally? updated thread - Works fine locally

Comment: Please provide `docker run` command you used.

Comment: I'm not using docker run manually, im running `gcloud builds submit . --config=cloudbuild.yaml` which will build the image and deploy it on app engine... but locally i'm using  `docker run -it -d -p 8080:8080 144005a4e426`

Comment: whats the url you used to access the site. Is it 127.0.0.1:8080 or machine-ip:8080. Or something else. where you getting 502 error.

Comment: @mchawre thats my gcloud project server : `https://[PROJECT_NAME].appspot.com/`

Comment: I just deployed an express app with almost the same configuration (socket io on 8080) and this works perfectly.